# Select month in MMM format

Tags: sql-server

How do I select a month where the month field is in MMM format, eg. iMonth field has the months listed as Jan, Feb, Mar. I used datepart function but the destination field type is in nvarchar format and I get the below error. 
Error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Mar       ' to data type int.

When I use dataname function the query runs but no output is pulled.

Comment: What to you what to convert to what, exactly?

Comment: And can you show the `datepart` syntax you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Options

1. Convert your `iMonth` to an actual `date` type
2. Create a lookup table for the 3 digit months and `JOIN` your queries.